# Data property value extraction from an instance of an ontology

Tags: java, eclipse, rdf, jena, ontology

I am trying to display the data property values of the instances of my ontology.  I am using Jena for this purpose.  My instances are as follows:

```xml
<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/Ontology1365003423152.owl#Mailbomb -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="&Ontology1365003423152;Mailbomb">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&Ontology1365003423152;Attack"/>
    <Ontology1365003423152:HasService>smtp</Ontology1365003423152:HasService>
    <Ontology1365003423152:HasFlag>SF</Ontology1365003423152:HasFlag>
    <Ontology1365003423152:HasDuration>1</Ontology1365003423152:HasDuration>
    <Ontology1365003423152:hasSrcBytes>2599</Ontology1365003423152:hasSrcBytes>
    <Ontology1365003423152:HasType>Mailbomb</Ontology1365003423152:HasType>
    <Ontology1365003423152:HasProtocol>tcp</Ontology1365003423152:HasProtocol>
    <Ontology1365003423152:hasDestBytes>293</Ontology1365003423152:hasDestBytes>
</NamedIndividual>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/Ontology1365003423152.owl#Smurf -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="&Ontology1365003423152;Smurf">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&Ontology1365003423152;Attack"/>
    <Ontology1365003423152:HasService>ecr_i</Ontology1365003423152:HasService>
    <Ontology1365003423152:HasProtocol>icmp</Ontology1365003423152:HasProtocol>
    <Ontology1365003423152:hasSrcBytes>1032</Ontology1365003423152:hasSrcBytes>
    <Ontology1365003423152:HasFlag>SF</Ontology1365003423152:HasFlag>
    <Ontology1365003423152:HasType>Smurf</Ontology1365003423152:HasType>
    <Ontology1365003423152:hasDestBytes>0</Ontology1365003423152:hasDestBytes>
    <Ontology1365003423152:HasDuration>0</Ontology1365003423152:HasDuration>
</NamedIndividual>
```

And my code in Java using Jena is as follows:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String a[] =  new String [7];
            OntProperty p[] = new OntProperty [7];  
     OntModel inf = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
     InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);
     if (in == null) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
     }
     inf.read(in, "");
     OntClass clas =inf.getOntClass("http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/Ontology1365003423152.owl#Attack");
     p[0] = inf.getOntProperty("HasProtocol");
     p[1] = inf.getOntProperty("HasService");
     p[2] = inf.getOntProperty("HasDuration");
     p[3] = inf.getOntProperty("HasFlag");
     p[4] = inf.getOntProperty("hasSrcBytes");
     p[5] = inf.getOntProperty("hasDestBytes");
     p[6] = inf.getOntProperty("HasType");
     ExtendedIterator instances = clas.listInstances();
     Individual instance = null;
     while (instances.hasNext()) {
       instance = (Individual) instances.next();
       System.out.println(a[0] = instance.getPropertyValue(p[0]).toString());
       System.out.println(a[1] = instance.getPropertyValue(p[1]).toString());
       System.out.println(a[2] = instance.getPropertyValue(p[2]).toString());
       System.out.println(a[3] = instance.getPropertyValue(p[3]).toString());
       System.out.println(a[4] = instance.getPropertyValue(p[4]).toString());
       System.out.println(a[5] = instance.getPropertyValue(p[5]).toString());
       System.out.println(a[6] = instance.getPropertyValue(p[6]).toString());
     }
}
```

Now the first iteration of printing only prints zero whereas the second only 293 (7 times 0 followed by 7 times 293). I guess I am doing something wrong as it's retrieving the same value for everything. The way I see it is only printing the last data property values of each instance.

Answer (score 2):

Just as you need to specify the whole IRI in

```
inf.getOntClass("http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/Ontology1365003423152.owl#Attack");
```

you need to specify the whole IRI in

```
p[0] = inf.getOntProperty("HasProtocol");
```

Since there's probably not an OntProperty with the IRI `HasProtocol`, `p[0]` (and the rest) are being set to `null`, and in many places the Jena API interprets `null` as a wildcard.  So

```
instance.getPropertyValue(p[0]).toString());
```

is just querying the model for a triple with `instance` as the subject and any predicate and any object.  Jena just happens to return the same triple for each `instance` every time.  I'd guess that it's not the last one mentioned in the file, but rather the [instance, hasDestBytes, ...] triple, based on some artifact of how triples are stored or indexed.  Either way, since it's just the result of a wildcard match, the behavior probably isn't precisely defined.  Do something like this instead and you should be all set:

```
String ns = "http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/Ontology1365003423152.owl#";
OntClass clas = inf.getOntClass(ns + "Attack");
p[0] = inf.getOntProperty(ns + "HasProtocol");
p[1] = inf.getOntProperty(ns + "HasService");
```